# How to implement Elastos with PHP

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am new to Elastos. I want to implement it in my website develop in CI. Can anyone help me and tell me how to implement Elastos in PHP or using javascript.
I have  refer following sites but not find any particular help.

> https://github.com/elastos
>
> https://github.com/elastos/Elastos

Comment: it appears they do not have a php sdk which you can plug in as of yet

Comment: I have also search here and in other websites but not find any solution for php. It only provide sdk for android, ios m i right ?